# View Controller: how to correctly initialize values that depend on NIB

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller

I'm wondering what the best way is to initialize values that depend on objects in a NIB. For example, let's say I have a `UIView` that gets a custom `cornerRadius` and `borderColor`.

Right now what I do is

```
@interface MyViewController ()
@property (nonatomic, weak) IBOutlet UIView *roundyView;
@end

@implementation MyViewController

- (id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        // (!) Can't assign to roundyView, hasn't been loaded from NIB yet
        // ...
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // Ahh, NIB loaded, roundyView has a value
    self.roundyView.layer.cornerRadius = 5.0f;
    self.roundyView.layer.borderColor = [UIColor redColor].CGColor;
}

@end
```

So far, so good. Next I add a setter, so I can change the border color from elsewhere in the program.

```
@property (nonatomic, strong) UIColor *roundBorderColor;
```

And

```
-(void)setRoundBorderColor:(UIColor*)roundBorderColor {
    _roundBorderColor = roundBorderColor;
    self.roundyView.layer.borderColor = roundBorderColor.CGColor;
}
```

The problem is that I usually call that accessor while instantiating the class, but before it is presented. Something like

```
MyViewController *vc = [[MyViewController alloc] initWithNibName:@"MyViewController" 
                                                          bundle:nil];
// Setting the color, NIB hasn't loaded though (!)
vc.roundBorderColor = [UIColor yellowColor];
[self presentViewController:vc animated:YES completion:nil];
```

This doesn't work, since the setter runs before `viewDidLoad`. So instead I usually put cruft like this:

```
-(void)viewDidLoad {
    // ...
    if (_roundBorderColor != nil) {
        // The setter was already called somewhere,
        // call it again now that we have the NIB
        [self setRoundBorderColor:_roundBorderColor];
    }
}
```

Is there a cleaner way to deal with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Goto the identity inspector in the Interface Builder (third option from the left in the interface builder view), and for your view - set the "User Defined Runtime Attributes" and add the following:
Keypath: layer.cornerRadius Value: number, 5.

Unfortunately - this doesn't seem to work for the border color, as the UI allows only "Color" but not CGColor.
A simple workaround to keep your code clean from colors would be to set a user defined property to your view controller and set it via your nib.
In your view controller:

```
@property (nonatomic,strong) UIColor* borderColor;
```

And then in the interface builder, set the color via User Defined Runtime Attributes to whatever you want.
Then set the color to the layer's border in `viewDidLoad`.
Involves some code and not just UI Builder, but at least there is no need to specify the color in the code.


Or, if you just want to set the color using code and don't want to wait for "viewDidLoad" you can do something like:

```
-(void)setRoundBorderColor:(UIColor*)roundBorderColor {
    [self view]; // force view load from nib
    self.roundyView.layer.borderColor = roundBorderColor.CGColor;
}
```

Comment: Thanks, I didn't know about "User Defined Runtime Attributes". It's odd, there seems to be almost no documentation of this feature. A [Google search](https://www.google.com/search?q="user+defined+runtime+attributes"+site%3Aapple.com) with "site:apple.com" brings up 20 results from mailing lists and no official docs. Some other good articles: [here](http://spirit-blog.logdown.com/posts/205363-about-custom-view-and-runtime-attributes) and [here](http://samdods.github.io/blog/2014/04/08/user-defined-runtime-attributes-in-interface-builder/).

Answer (score 1):

This problem is elegantly solved starting in Xcode 6 by using the IBInspectable feature. For example, in a UIButton subclass:

```
@IBInspectable var borderColor : UIColor? {
    get {
        let cg = self.layer.borderColor
        return cg == nil ? nil : UIColor(CGColor: cg!)
    }
    set {
        self.layer.borderColor = newValue?.CGColor ?? nil
    }
}
```

An instance of this button in the storyboard / xib now shows a "borderColor" color pop-up menu in the Attributes inspector.

[image]

This sets a UIColor, but our property is just a facade for the layer's `borderColor` and translates between UIColor and CGColor.

Answer (score 0):

You can make it a little cleaner by initialising your property in `initWithNibName` - that way you can safely access the property in `viewDidLoad` without the check.

```
-(id)initWithNibName:(NSString *)nibNameOrNil 
               bundle:(NSBundle *)nibBundleOrNil {
    self = [super initWithNibName:nibNameOrNil bundle:nibBundleOrNil];
    if (self) {
        _roundBorderColor = [UIColor redColor];
    }
    return self;
}

-(void)viewDidLoad {
// ...

    [self setRoundBorderColor:_roundBorderColor];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should use **isViewLoaded** method.

```
- (void)setRoundBorderColor:(UIColor *)roundBorderColor {
    _roundBorderColor = roundBorderColor;

    // would be launched only if view is initialised
    if ([self isViewLoaded]) {
        self.roundyView.layer.borderColor = roundBorderColor.CGColor;
    }
}

- (void)setBorderRagius:... // same idea as before

- (void)viewDidLoad {
    self.roundyView.layer.cornerRadius = self.cornerRadius;
    self.roundyView.layer.borderColor = self.borderColor;
}
```

And you need to set some default values to **cornerRadius** and **borderColor** properties. And do nothing if **nil** value is going to be set.

Comment: Nice, I didn't know there was a `isViewLoaded` method. Thanks